# Can amqplite act as a server to a WindowsAzure.ServiceBus client?

Tags: c#, testing, amqp, azureservicebus

I want to do black-box testing of a messaging client library that uses the [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) nuget package ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus/)) to send and receive messages to/from Microsoft ServiceBus queues.

My goal is to create integration tests for the messaging client library, but not communicate with an actual Microsoft Service Bus server.

Looking at the [amqplite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) library, I was hoping that I could create an AMQP host using amqplite, and configure the messaging client library to communicate with this host, instead of an actual Microsoft Service Bus.

Here is my custom AMQP host, using amqplite:

```
public class LinkProcessor : ILinkProcessor
{
    public void Process(AttachContext attachContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LinkProcessor.Attach!");
    }
}


var containerHost = new ContainerHost(new Uri("amqp://localhost:9876/"));
containerHost.RegisterLinkProcessor(new LinkProcessor());
containerHost.Open();
```

I register a ILinkProcessor on the containerHost so I can see on the console any connection attempts (based on my limited understanding of AMQP/AMQPlite this is what I believe a ILinkProcessor does).

The AMQP client below can connect, the server process outputs "LinkProcessor.Attach!" on the console.

```
async Task Main()
{
    await SendMessage("q2", "hello world");
}

async Task SendMessage(string queue, string message)
{
    var connection = await Connection.Factory.CreateAsync(new Address("amqp://localhost:9876/"));
    var session = new Session(connection);

    var msg = new Message(message);
    var sender = new SenderLink(session, "sender-link", queue);
    await sender.SendAsync(msg);
    await sender.CloseAsync();
    await session.CloseAsync();
    await connection.CloseAsync();
}
```

Back to the messaging client library that I want to test:

- The library is configured using a connection string, a working connection string looks like this (I assume the connection string format is one defined by WindowsAzure.ServiceBus):

  `Endpoint=sb://xxx/yyy;StsEndpoint=https://nnn:NNNN/xxx;RuntimePort=NNNN;ManagementPort=NNNN;OAuthUsername=xxx;OAuthPassword=yyy`
- I changed the config string to the following:

  `Endpoint=amqp://localhost:9876/q2`
- When I run the test client, the following happens:

  - The client throws an exception: You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing.
  - I see no activity on the AMQPlite host end, i.e. no "LinkProcessor.Attach!" message on the console.

Question:

- Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? I.e. is there a way to configure a AMQPlite host so that it can accept connections from a WindowsAzure.ServiceBus client ?

Comment: It is possible but requires some work on setting up the amqplite listener. Please find more details under the issue on the amqpnetlite github repo.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Link to the github issue: https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/issues/176